# Azul Zulu JDK 8 with Azul Mission Control doesn't profile methods

Tags: java-8, jmc, azul-zulu

I'm using Azul Zulu JDK 8 (v1.8.0_202) with Azul ZMC 7.1.1 on Win10, and I'm creating a 20s Flight Recording of a running JVM. The resultant data displays various captured metrics (e.g. CPU Usage Heap Usage, Allocation etc) but no Method Profiling data. I've tried with both a Time Fixed recording and the Continuous recording - both have the same issue. The highlighted section in the following screenshot indicates where I'd expect to see method profiling data:

[image: ZMC screenshot]

Is there some trick to enable this? I can't any reference to this in the somewhat sparse documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Azul Zulu [documentation](https://docs.azul.com/zulu/zulurelnotes-archive/ZuluReleaseNotes/ReleaseDetails122-1131-1130-838-837-729-728.htm) there was a bug with Method Profiling in Zulu 8 fixed in Zulu8.38 (8u212).

Please, try a newer version for Zulu8: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-8-lts&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk

Also, make sure you've enabled Method Profiling while starting recoding:

[image]

Comment: Method profiling is enabled. I've updated the question with versions.

Comment: @jon-hanson, As far as I recall 8u202 didn't support Method Profiling yet, can you try a recent one? Like 8u262 https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-8-lts&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk

Comment: Yep, that fixed it.